# What is the future of sharepoint on-premise?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I am a SharePoint administrator I want to know the future of SharePoint on-premises in market ?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right question fro this forum.  SharePoint future is bright! Microsoft recently announced that they will continue to invest SharePoint on premises.  Considering, moving to the cloud is not an option for everyone, SharePoint on-premises is not going away soon for sure!

Comment: SharePoint 2016 is said to be the last on-premise version, but then again, we don't know for sure.

Comment: @mike "We’re committed to our on-premises and have no plans to make SharePoint Server 2016 our final version of our on-premises server."

Comment: This is news to me. This came out a week ago, but until that point it's always been implied SharePoint 2016 was the last on-premise version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Future of SharePoint is bright, but as an admin, we have to shift the gears as future of SharePoint depends upon hybrid. Like all future updates are cloud born then on Onprem. Like SharePoint framework, 1st release in the cloud now will be released on Orem.

Here is an answer from Bill bear for next versions question.

> Q: Will there be another version of SharePoint on-premises? A: We’re
>   committed to our on-premises and have no plans to make SharePoint
>   Server 2016 our final version of our on-premises server.

Read the complete blog.https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2017/05/16/sharepoint-server-2016-and-beyond/

Answer (score 2):

Flexibility in developing Custom solutions is still with On Prem. SharePoint online recently removed support for sandbox solutions which further degrades the customization. We had to move our solutions to another on Prem server or Azure.

Advised to learn MS Azure which will have more market in coming future.